# How to distribute text evenly

Tags: text-object, duplicate

I have some text I need to type out, and distribute evenly. I used the Array modifier, thinking I can make as many duplicates I need, add the space between the text, and then add the modifier and change the text to the actual wording I need. But this modifier cannot be applied to text. And converting the text to mesh o curves loses it's editability,

Im aware with Shift + D, and then Shift + R will make duplicates, but if I need to change position of the text, I need to repeat the process again.

Any other methods to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can Alt D and Shift R, and if you need to increase the space between the text, choose Options > Transform Affect Only Locations? You could also use Instancing

Comment: Menu "Object/Convert/To Mesh", if the point of your question is to apply the modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do that with GeoNodes. If you don't want GN, you could use *Instancing*, first create an edge that you subdivide, parent the text object to it:

[image]

Activate the *Instancing > Vertices* option of the edge, the text will be instanced on each vertex of the mesh:

[image]

If, for example, you want to increase the gap between the instances, scale the mesh in *Edit* mode:

[image]

If you want to edit the text, select it in the *Outliner* (you'll find it under the edge object as it is its child) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change spacing between objects in Blender in various ways. They certainly apply to text objects same way as to any other, so after using  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd>  and  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>   to duplicate, move and repeat, you can definitely change the spacing of your objects without any trouble.

You can simply scale all your selected objects with Affect Only: Locations checked for example:

[image]

All functionality of transform operators is available to you. You can choose transform pivot, snapping, use numerical input and so on.
Don't forget you can use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>  for anything as well, so you can repeat only moving.